# What to use for sore nostrils?

Tags: common-cold, nose, topical-cream-gel, effectiveness, nostrils

I am using this at the moment : [Country Comfort Herbal Savvy Comfrey](http://www.iherb.com/country-comfort-herbal-savvy-comfrey-aloe-vera-2-oz-57-g/6380), but I have read that oil based stuff can cause pneumonia. What to use then ?